# Map a composite key inside a composite key hibernate xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This is what I would like to do, map an object to another table that has the same primary keys.  The below is an example, basically I have one object with a composite key that has a composite key for ANOTHER table, but I don't know how to include both in order to create the proper object key.  I highlighted the row that is wrong, it only includes one of the properties for the key.

```
  <class name="BusinessRuleObject" table="BUSINESS_RULE_OBJECTS" schema="DB">
    <composite-id name="businessRuleObjectId" class="BusinessRuleObjectId">
      <key-property name="sameIdCode" column="ID_CD" />
      **<key-many-to-one name="businessRule" class="BusinessRule" column="BUSINESS_RULE" />**
    </composite-id>
    <!-- ... STUFF GOES HERE -->
  </class>

  <class name="BusinessRule" table="BUSINESS_RULE_STRINGS" schema="DB">
    <composite-id name="businessRule2ID" class="BusinessRule2ID">
      <key-property name="sameIdCode" column="ID_CD" />
      <key-property name="businessRuleCode" column="BUSINESS_RULE" />
    </composite-id>
    <!-- TOTALLY DIFFERENT STUFF GOES HERE -->
   </class>
```

Comment: is there any master/detail relationship between the two ?

Comment: No, for all intents and purposes they could be the same table with the exception of the non-primarykey data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one properties of the composite foreign key `businessRule` is included, because the `<key-many-to-one` only declare one column `BUSINESS_RULE`. It should declare the two column of the composite key it is referencing `BUSINESS_RULE` and `ID_CD` in your example. By adding the `ID_CD` column to the `<key-many-to-one` element you need to remove or rename the column of `<key-property name="sameIdCode" column="ID_CD" />` element.

The association `<key-many-to-one` to `businessRule` object should be mapped like this:

```
<composite-id name="businessRuleObjectId" class="BusinessRuleObjectId"> 

  <key-many-to-one name="businessRule" class="BusinessRule" >
     <column name="ID_CD" />
     <column name="BUSINESS_RULE" />
  </key-many-to-one>

</composite-id>
```

> **Hibernate reference documenation**
>   [5.1.7. composite-id](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid)
>   [Components as composite identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html#components-compositeid)