# hibernate: many-to-one mapping via xml

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I'm facing some difficulties, trying to set up many-to-one relationship for two tables:
USERS and SUBSCRIBERS

(the main idea here is that users can save references on other users)

USERS table contain theese fields: |USER_ID|USER_PASSWORD|
While SUBSCRIBERS conains: |SUBSCRIBER_ID|USER_ID|, where:
1. Both fields are included in Primary Key
2. Both fields are foreign keys referencing to USER_ID from USERS.
There are no exception while saving User to a database.
But when I call code: 
(after creating 2 users inside DB - with first_u USER_ID, and second_u USER_ID)

```java
hibernate_session.beginTransaction();
subscr = new Subscription("first_u", "second_u");
hibernate_session.save(subscr);
hibernate_session.getTransaction().commit();
```

***I get this exception:***

```java
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of player.database.hibernate.entities.User.userID
    org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:64)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:223)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4601)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4313)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:276)
    org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:455)
    org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:153)
    org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:343)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2636)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2604)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2883)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3386)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    player.debugg.FriendRegistration.doGet(FriendRegistration.java:39)
    player.debugg.FriendRegistration.doPost(FriendRegistration.java:20)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

***Here are code snipets for entity classes and hbm.xml:***

```java
package player.database.hibernate.entities; 
public class User
{

    private String userID;
    private String userPassword;


    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(String login, String password)
    {
        this.setUserID(login);
        this.setUserPassword(password);
    }

    public void setUserID(String id)
    {
        if((id!=null)&&(!id.equals("")))
            this.userID = id;
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("User ID setter exception: empty or null");
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String password)
    {
        if((password!=null)&&(!password.equals("")))
            this.userPassword = password;
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("User password setter exception: empty or null");
    }

    public String getUserID()
    {
        return this.userID;
    }

    public String getUserPassword()
    {
        return this.userPassword;
    }
}
```

---

```java
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping package="player.database.hibernate.entities">
      <class name="User" table="USERS">
        <id name="userID" column="USER_ID">
          <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="userPassword" column="USER_PASS"/>
      </class>
```

```java
package player.database.hibernate.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Subscription implements Serializable
{
    private String subscriberID;
    private String userID;

    public Subscription()
    {
    }

    public Subscription(String subscriberID, String userID)
    {
        this.setSubscriberID(subscriberID);
        this.setUserID(userID);
    }

    public void setSubscriberID(String subscriberID) {
        if((subscriberID!=null)&&(!subscriberID.equals("")))
            this.subscriberID = subscriberID;
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Subscription subscriberID setter error: null or empty string");
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        if((userID!=null)&&(!userID.equals("")))
            this.userID = userID;
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Subscription subscriberID setter error: null or empty string");
    }

    public String getSubscriberID() {
        return subscriberID;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Subscription){
            Subscription subscription = (Subscription) obj;

            if(!subscription.getSubscriberID().equals(subscriberID)){
                return false;
            }

            if(!subscription.getUserID().equals(userID)){
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return subscriberID.hashCode() + userID.hashCode();
    }

}
```

---

```java
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="player.database.hibernate.entities">
  <class name="Subscription" table="SUBSCRIBERS">

      <composite-id>
          <key-many-to-one name="subscriberID" column="SUBSCRIBER_ID" class="User"/>
          <key-many-to-one name="userID" column="USER_ID" class="User"/>
      </composite-id>
  </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

P.S. I am using a way described here http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/ComposedID.htm
to create a composite key. I assume it works fine, because it outputs theese in console:

```java
Hibernate: create table SUBSCRIBERS (SUBSCRIBER_ID varchar(255) not null, USER_ID varchar(255) not null, primary key (SUBSCRIBER_ID, USER_ID))
Hibernate: create table USERS (USER_ID varchar(255) not null, USER_PASS varchar(255), primary key (USER_ID))
Hibernate: alter table SUBSCRIBERS add constraint FKnh93vk6v0ivt3a42hbaa7ffk5 foreign key (SUBSCRIBER_ID) references USERS (USER_ID)
Hibernate: alter table SUBSCRIBERS add constraint FKodh9g832cfmbqtsgtixky9j8j foreign key (USER_ID) references USERS (USER_ID)
```

I would really appreciate any help on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying that the Subscription class has a many-to-one association with the User class. I think there is no association defined as such. If there was  an association, the Subscription class would have

```
private User user;

public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user= user;
}
```

Also I don`t see any  mapping in subscription table

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I want here for Subscription is to have two fields of type of User's table primary key. Is there an opportunity of creating a User field for S. but bind to a table only it's userID??? <br/>If I am following your advice, then my User class should satisfy Serializable, equals() and hashcode() implementation?

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070150/map-a-composite-key-inside-a-composite-key-hibernate-xml

Comment: That still seem very unclear for me. Why jboss User Guide uses annotations only...<br/> As far as I understand, composite key without usiing Embeddable or IdClass is deprecated.<br/> may declaring User variables in Subscription class like you mention and then write in xml:

Comment: <class name="Subscription" table="SUBSCRIBERS"><br/>
      <composite-id><br/>
          <key-many-to-one name="subscriberID" class="User"><br/>
              <column name="USER_ID" /><br/>
          </key-many-to-one><br/>
          <key-many-to-one name="userID" class="User"><br/>
              <column name="USER_ID" /><br/>
          </key-many-to-one><br/>
      </composite-id><br/>
  </class> <br/>Can it work that way?

Comment: This way it throws an exception: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: player.database.hibernate.entities.Subscription column: USER_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: Yes! It worked. With User fields in Subscriptions and a little change in xml: <composite-id>
          <key-many-to-one name="subscriberID" class="User">
              <column name="SUBSCRIBER_ID" />
          </key-many-to-one>
          <key-many-to-one name="userID" class="User">
              <column name="USER_ID" />
          </key-many-to-one>
      </composite-id> Thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

For getting my code working, i replaced Strings fields in Subscription class to User fields (and of course getters and setters). My subscription.hbm.xml changed to following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="player.database.hibernate.entities">
  <class name="Subscription" table="SUBSCRIBERS">
      <composite-id>
          <key-many-to-one name="subscriberID" class="User">
              <column name="SUBSCRIBER_ID" />
          </key-many-to-one>
          <key-many-to-one name="userID" class="User">
              <column name="USER_ID" />
          </key-many-to-one>
      </composite-id>
  </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

With such configuration Hibernate ceates tables as follows:

```
Hibernate: create table SUBSCRIBERS (SUBSCRIBER_ID varchar(255) not null, USER_ID varchar(255) not null, primary key (SUBSCRIBER_ID, USER_ID))
Hibernate: create table USERS (USER_ID varchar(255) not null, USER_PASS varchar(255), primary key (USER_ID))
Hibernate: alter table SUBSCRIBERS add constraint FKnh93vk6v0ivt3a42hbaa7ffk5 foreign key (SUBSCRIBER_ID) references USERS (USER_ID)
Hibernate: alter table SUBSCRIBERS add constraint FKodh9g832cfmbqtsgtixky9j8j foreign key (USER_ID) references USERS (USER_ID)
```

Which is exactly what I wanted. Hope it will help to someone.